# Regex: If string not starting with character

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I'm using this regex for finding URLs to make them clickable links with html:

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)
```

Unfortunately this will also work if a link is already hyperlinked like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">My hyperlink</a>
```

My idea is to make the regex only work if there is no `"` in front of `https` (or `http` or `ftp`).

I tried to add `^(?!\".*$)` in front of the pattern but it's not working.

How can I do that?

Comment: `(?!` is negative lookahead. Use negative lookbehind instead, right before the `(http...`

Comment: `(?<!\")` in front of the pattern seems to work!

Comment: If you just want to check for the "", check out this regex. https://regexr.com/463dc